# Displaying time from a UILabel to another UILabel with Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have two UILabels where on one of them, it shows a stopwatch(lbl1) and on the other label(sentence) I want it to show the final time after pressing the stop button for the timer. On the sentence label I have it saying "Your time is:" and my goal is to display the final time after "Your time is:" For example: "Your time is: 00:01:24". So far I've managed to have the final time pop up on the console but not on the actual label. Can someone please help? thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   
  
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!         // Where the timer shows up
    var time = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    

    @IBAction func start1(_ sender: UIButton)       // code for the start button
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
       
    }
   

    
    @IBAction func stop1(_ sender: UIButton)    // code for the stop button
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        let timing = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: time)
        let timeString = makeTimeString(hours: timing.0, minutes: timing.1, seconds: timing.2)
        lbl1.text = timeString
        
        let totalTime = timeString
        print(totalTime)                        // displays the time on the console
        
    }
   
    
    @IBAction func reset1(_ sender: UIButton)   // code for the reset button
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0
        lbl1.text = ("00 : 00 : 00")
    }
   

    @objc func action() -> Void                   // timer add up
    {
        time = time + 1
        let timing = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: time)
        let timeString = makeTimeString(hours: timing.0, minutes: timing.1, seconds: timing.2)
        lbl1.text = timeString
        
    }
   

       
    
    
    func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
     {
         return ((seconds / 3600), ((seconds % 3600) / 60),((seconds % 3600) % 60))
     }
     



    func makeTimeString(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds : Int) -> String
     {
         var timeString = ""
         timeString += String(format: "%02d", hours)
         timeString += " : "
         timeString += String(format: "%02d", minutes)
         timeString += " : "
         timeString += String(format: "%02d", seconds)
         return timeString
     }
 

    
   
    
  
    @IBOutlet weak var sentence: UILabel!               // where the time is supposed to show up
    var words =  "Your time is: "
    
    
    
  
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sentence.text = (self.words as? String)
        
        
        print(self.words)
        

    }

}
```

Comment: You need another outlet for your second label and then you just assign the string to its `text`property.  I suggest that you don't rely on 1 second timer ticks. A `Timer` isn't particularly accurate. It is better to create a `Date` to represent the start time (simply store `Date()` when you start) and then you can use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to calculate elapsed time. Run the timer faster than a second (say, 0.2 seconds) for smoother updates.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit. I recommend using `didSet`.

didset is obsever property in swift.

Use to show updated values to View

```swift
    @IBAction func stop1(_ sender: UIButton) 
   
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        let timing = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: time)
        let timeString = makeTimeString(hours: timing.0, minutes: timing.1, seconds: timing.2)
        lbl1.text = timeString
        
        totalTime = timeString                    
        
    }

    var words =  "Your time is: "
    var totalTime: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.sentence.text = "Your time is: \(totalTime)"
        }
    }
```

I used the `didSet` to make the `totalTime renew` whenever a new value came in.